# Error loading data with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Each time I press the button to load the AJAX, I load the start screen with everything (header, menu and footer) apart from not loading the data from the table I request. I get this warning in the console:

> [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check.

I tried to put async: true and also the script at the end of the document, but nothing.

> INDEX.PHP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sistema de Administración de Envíos - Pedidos</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        require('components/menu.php');
    ?>
    <div class="main">
        <div id="top-pedidos">
                <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
                        <div class="input-group-addon"><button id="buttonFechaPedido" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button></div>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="inputFechaPedido" name="fecha">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
                    <div class="input-group-addon"><button id="buttonNumeroPedido"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button></div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputNumeroPedido" name="npedido" placeholder="Nº pedido">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
                    <div class="input-group-addon"><button id="buttonEstadoPedido"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i></button></div>
                    <select class="custom-select mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" id="inputEstadoPedido" name="estado">
                        <option value="vacio" selected></option>
                        <option value="Pendiente">Pendiente</option>
                        <option value="Aceptado">Aceptado</option>
                        <option value="Rechazado">Rechazado</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            <a href="nuevo-pedido.php"><button class="newPedido btn btn-primary">Nuevo Pedido</button></a>
        </div>
        <div class="tables">
            <?php 
            require('sql/sql-pedidos.php');
            ?>
            <div id="tablaPedido">
                <p id="emptyFecha" class="mistake red">Debes poner una fecha</p>
                <p id="errorFecha" class="mistake red">Ha ocurrido un error con la fecha</p>
                <p id="emptyNumero" class="mistake red">Debes poner un número de pedido</p>
                <p id="errorNumero" class="mistake red">Ha ocurrido un error con el número de pedido</p>
                <p id="emptyEstado" class="mistake red">Debes seleccionar un estado</p>
                <p id="errorEstado" class="mistake red">Ha ocurrido un error con el estado</p>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php
        require('components/footer.php');
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

> loadAjax.php

```
<?php
    //Tabla inicial sin parámetros de búsqueda
    require('conexionbd.php');

    $general = 'SELECT * FROM pedidos';
    $result = mysql_query($general) or die('Consulta fallida: ' . mysql_error());

    echo "<table class='table table-striped table-pedidos-g'>\n";
    echo "<tr class='superior'>
            <td>Nº pedido</td>
            <td>Fecha</td>
            <td>Descuento</td>
            <td>Cliente</td>
            <td>Estado</td>
        </tr>";

    while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        echo "\t<tr>\n";
        foreach ($line as $col_value) {
            echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
        }
        echo "\t</tr>\n";
    }
    echo "</table>\n";
?>

<script>
            $('#buttonFechaPedido').click(function() {
            $('.table-pedidos-g').hide();
            $('.table-pedidos-n').hide();
            $('.table-pedidos-e').hide();
            var valorFecha = $('#inputFechaPedido').val();
            if (valorFecha.length == 0){
                $('#emptyFecha').removeClass('mistake');
            }
            else{
$(document).ready(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    data:  valorFecha,
                    url:   'pedidos/pfechas.php',
                    type:  'post',
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        $("#tablaPedido").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");
                    },
                    error:function (){
                        $('#errorFecha').removeClass('mistake');
                    },
                    success:  function (response) {
                        $("#tablaPedido").html(response);
                    }
                });
});
            }       
        });
</script>

<script>
    $('#buttonNumeroPedido').click(function() {
        $('.table-pedidos-g').hide();
        $('.table-pedidos-f').hide();
        $('.table-pedidos-e').hide();
        var valorNumero =$('#inputNumeroPedido').val();
        if (valorNumero.length == 0){
            $('#emptyNumero').removeClass('mistake');
        }
        else{
$(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                data:  valorNumero,
                url:   'pedidos/pnumero.php',
                type:  'post',
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#tablaPedido").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");
                },
                error:function (){
                    $('#errorNumero').removeClass('mistake');
                },
                success:  function (response) {
                    $("#tablaPedido").html(response);
                }
            });
});
        }       
    });
</script>

<script>
    $('#buttonEstadoPedido').click(function() {
        $('.table-pedidos-g').hide();
        $('.table-pedidos-n').hide();
        $('.table-pedidos-f').hide();
        var valorEstado =$('#inputEstadoPedido').val();
        if (valorEstado == 'vacio'){
            $('#emptyEstado').removeClass('mistake');
        }
        else{
$(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                data:  valorEstado,
                url:   'pedidos/pestado.php',
                type:  'post',
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#tablaPedido").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");
                },
                error:function (){
                    $('#errorEstado').removeClass('mistake');
                },
                success:  function (response) {
                    $("#tablaPedido").html(response);
                }
            });
});
        }       
    });
</script>
```

> pfechas.php

```
<?php
    require('../conexionbd.php');

    // Realizar una consulta MySQL
    $fechas = 'SELECT * FROM pedidos WHERE fecha_pdo = $_POST["valorFecha"]';
    $result = mysql_query($fechas) or die('Consulta fallida: ' . mysql_error());

    // Imprimir los resultados en HTML
    echo "<table class='table table-striped table-pedidos-f'>\n";
    echo "<tr class='superior'>
            <td>Nº pedido</td>
            <td>Fecha</td>
            <td>Descuento</td>
            <td>Cliente</td>
            <td>Estado</td>
        </tr>";
    while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        echo "\t<tr>\n";
        foreach ($line as $col_value) {
            echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
        }
        echo "\t</tr>\n";
    }
    echo "</table>\n";

    // Liberar resultados
    mysql_free_result($result);

    // Cerrar la conexión
    mysql_close($link);
?>
```

> pnumero.php

```
<?php
    require('../conexionbd.php');

    // Realizar una consulta MySQL
    $numeros = 'SELECT * FROM pedidos WHERE numero_pdo = $_POST["valorNumero"]';
    $result = mysql_query($fnumeros) or die('Consulta fallida: ' . mysql_error());

    // Imprimir los resultados en HTML
    echo "<table class='table table-striped table-pedidos-n'>\n";
    echo "<tr class='superior'>
            <td>Nº pedido</td>
            <td>Fecha</td>
            <td>Descuento</td>
            <td>Cliente</td>
            <td>Estado</td>
        </tr>";
    while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        echo "\t<tr>\n";
        foreach ($line as $col_value) {
            echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
        }
        echo "\t</tr>\n";
    }
    echo "</table>\n";

    // Liberar resultados
    mysql_free_result($result);

    // Cerrar la conexión
    mysql_close($link);
?>
```

> pestado.php

```
<?php
    require('../conexionbd.php');

    // Realizar una consulta MySQL
    $estados = 'SELECT * FROM pedidos WHERE estado = $_POST["valorEstado"]';
    $result = mysql_query($estados) or die('Consulta fallida: ' . mysql_error());

    // Imprimir los resultados en HTML
    echo "<table class='table table-striped table-pedidos-e'>\n";
    echo "<tr class='superior'>
            <td>Nº pedido</td>
            <td>Fecha</td>
            <td>Descuento</td>
            <td>Cliente</td>
            <td>Estado</td>
        </tr>";
    while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        echo "\t<tr>\n";
        foreach ($line as $col_value) {
            echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
        }
        echo "\t</tr>\n";
    }
    echo "</table>\n";

    // Liberar resultados
    mysql_free_result($result);

    // Cerrar la conexión
    mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the error message is coming from your ajax calls here? Do you have a full stacktrace? If you remove this code but still import the other scripts, do you still get the error?

Comment: I changed this and now I have no warning, but it stays in beforeSend

$(document).ready(function() --->  $(function()
error: ----------> fail:
success: -----> done:

Comment: I don't understand that comment. You changed what? What stays in what? Are you missing some punctuation? Where are the `{` and `}`?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here and I thought you could see the text breaks.
I changed the "$ (document) .ready (function ()" to "$ (function ()", and within the function of ajax I changed the "error" to "fail" and the "success" to "done" .
The jquery error does not work anymore, but the ajax only executes the function set in "beforeSend"

Comment: The `$(function()` change shouldn't make a difference. Why have you used `fail` and `done`? I don't think they're meant to work. (They are names of methods on jqXHR objects in the newest jQuery, but that's something else.)

Comment: I am Spanish, and this question was also asked in the Spanish stackoverflow. Then a user advised me to change it for the above mentioned. I thought it was okay, since at least I did not get the warning.

Comment: If you get an error with the `error` function then it means something has gone wrong, and removing the function isn't going to fix it. I have no idea why the warning message went away.

Comment: can we see the  pedidos/pestado.php ,'pedidos/pnumero.php' and 'pedidos/pfechas.php', pages ?

Comment: Of course, I've already put